# Sphinx: Understanding Proximity Factor Ranking for a large field

Tags: sphinx

[This](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2010/08/17/how-sphinx-relevance-ranking-works/) document explains the sphinx proximity factor ranking algorithm (see section: *Phrase proximity factor*).

**Will the proximity factor ranker give a higher field weight if the keyword is found more than once in the field?**

eg. using similar logic to the referenced section of the linked document. For a single instance match phrase weight would be 2:

```
1) query = one two three, field = one and two three
field_phrase_weight = 2 (because 2-keyword long "two three" subphrase matched)
```

What about if the same phrase was matched twice? Would the weight be double?:

```
2) query = one two three, field = one and two three one and two three
field_phrase_weight = 4? (because 2-keyword long "two three" subphrase matched twice?)
```

I suspect that the answer to the above question is no - sphinx will return the same field weight whether the keyword/keyword subsequence is found multiple times. If this is the case, **how to make good use of the proximity algorithm for large sphinx fields like an essay if this will return the same field weight regardless of content size?** Especially given the go-to sphinx algorithm for searching is the proximity_bm25 ranker which relies very heavily on "proximity ranking" (for a multiple field document at least 60% of the algorithm would be weighted towards proximity ranking over bm25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the proximity factor ranker give a higher field weight if the keyword is found more than once in the field?

No. The same field weight will apply.

> eg. using similar logic to the referenced section of the linked document. For a single instance match phrase weight would be 2:
>
> 1) query = one two three, field = one and two three
>   field_phrase_weight = 2 (because 2-keyword long "two three" subphrase matched)
>
> What about if the same phrase was matched twice? Would the weight be double?:
>
> 2) query = one two three, field = one and two three one and two three
>   field_phrase_weight = 4? (because 2-keyword long "two three" subphrase matched twice?)

In this example, the weight would not be double in the 2nd query.

> how to make good use of the proximity algorithm for large sphinx fields like an essay if this will return the same field weight regardless of content size?

The only way I can figure is through a combination of the proximity to give the higher weights to multi keyword phrases, but also to give the BM25 enough weight in the algorithm to add value in providing the "rare keywords occurring more often in documents" factor. The BM25 part of the Proximity_BM25 ranking algorithm is designed for this purpose.

This is the proximity_bm25 expression: `sum(lcs*user_weight)*1000+bm25`, the bm25 component of this algorithm progressively becomes more irrelevant the more sphinx fields you have in a document as the `sum(lcs*user_weight)*1000` part of the formulate applies to each individual field while the `bm25` part of the equation applies to the document as a whole.

In my situation with 10 sphinx fields, the `bm25` was accounting for just 5% of the total weight - I bumped up the weight of the `bm25` portion of the formula to account for around 20% of the total weight changing the formula as such:

`sum(lcs*user_weight)*1000+bm25*4`